# Failed to connect to repository : Error performing command: git ls-remote -h git@gitlab.com

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab

I cannot get my Private project to link to Jenkins.

All I get is:

> Failed to connect to repository : Error performing command: git
>   ls-remote -h git@gitlab.com:MineJam/DiscordSync.git HEAD

whenever I try to put the link to the repository in. Any suggestions?

I've tried to look this up and change the link to a HTTPS link that still throws the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check in global tool configuration "git" path set is correct
2. Ensure the git repository path is correct. Follow the following syntax to mention url

ex. https://gitlab.com/username/Reponame.git

After mentioning path in source code management copy that and paste in browser window. You should navigate to your repository